# Autolayout not detecting frame size

Tags: ios, autolayout, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I'm converting my xib files to use autolayout but only certain devices have their frame size detected properly (iPad 2 and iPhone 4). The iPhone 6plus and iPhone 6 that I'm using doesn't detect the frame size properly. It detects the frame size of the view.

I've initiated the self.view.frame.size.height and self.view.frame.size.width in the viewWillAppear method but it's still not detecting the correct size. This is making my auto layout not scale properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: you're likely going to want to use size classes or relative spacing values (not frames directly) if you're interested in autolayout.

Comment: Did you add a launch image for iPhone 6 and 6 plus with the correct sizes?

Comment: the launch images were only for iPhone and iPad, there wasn't a launch image specifically for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus. How do I add a launch image for those 2 phones specifically?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method to get the correct size:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    //YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

The view final size is not setted until the call of the "viewDidLayoutSubviews" method. Here we will have the correct size of the view.
I hope that will resolve your issue.